sqlite db locked while iterating rows and writing to db in go
I'm trying to iterate over some records, call some API's to retrieve some information and write to the db again.
I'm writing to a different table of the query so there shouldn't be any conflict.
However while iterating the rows, and trying to call stmt.Exec on the insert statement, I get the database is locked error.
I can't close the connection or the rows either since I still need to iterate over them.
What options do I have in this case?
Is creating another db connection the only option?
Or is this some limitation in sqlite? Is there something we can do to overcome this limitation?

Have you tried executing SQL statement PRAGMA busy_timeout = 5000?

You can't use the same connection while you are iterating over the result of the query, because your connection is busy reading rows. Here are the options you could use:

Create a second connection explicitly as you mentioned.
Use a connection pool with at least two connections (more preferred).

